# access tally from php curl

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to insert data from php to tally using php curl,I have already succeeded in inserting data when i ran the code in tally in local machine by giving ip 127.0.0.1,but when i am trying it live curl is giving me error like connection timeout couldnot connect to host.
    I had also tried port forwarding.

```
        Below is my xml:

        <ENVELOPE>
  <HEADER>
    <TALLYREQUEST>Import Data</TALLYREQUEST>
  </HEADER>
  <BODY>
    <IMPORTDATA>
      <REQUESTDESC>
        <REPORTNAME>Vouchers</REPORTNAME>
        <STATICVARIABLES> </STATICVARIABLES>
      </REQUESTDESC>
      <REQUESTDATA>
        <TALLYMESSAGE xmlns:UDF="TallyUDF">
          <VOUCHER  VCHTYPE="Sales" Action="Create">
            <ISOPTIONAL>No</ISOPTIONAL>
            <VOUCHERTYPENAME>Sales</VOUCHERTYPENAME>
            <DATE>20130413</DATE>
            <EFFECTIVEDATE>20130413</EFFECTIVEDATE>
            <ISCANCELLED>No</ISCANCELLED>
            <USETRACKINGNUMBER>No</USETRACKINGNUMBER>
            <ISPOSTDATED>No</ISPOSTDATED>
            <DIFFACTUALQTY>No</DIFFACTUALQTY>
            <VOUCHERNUMBER>11</VOUCHERNUMBER>
            <REFERENCE>IS/11/13-14</REFERENCE>
            <PARTYLEDGERNAME>INFOSOL</PARTYLEDGERNAME>
            <NARRATION>Booked By: KUNAL SINGH | Used By: SANTOSH PARAB</NARRATION>
            <ASPAYSLIP>No</ASPAYSLIP>
            <ALTERID>11</ALTERID>
            <ALLLEDGERENTRIES.LIST>
              <REMOVEZEROENTRIES>No</REMOVEZEROENTRIES>
              <ISDEEMEDPOSITIVE>Yes</ISDEEMEDPOSITIVE>
              <LEDGERFROMITEM>No</LEDGERFROMITEM>
              <LEDGERNAME>INFOSOL</LEDGERNAME>
              <AMOUNT>-2200.00</AMOUNT>
              <BILLALLOCATIONS.LIST>
                <NAME>IS/11/13-14</NAME>
                <BILLTYPE>New Ref</BILLTYPE>
                <BILLCREDITPERIOD>20130413</BILLCREDITPERIOD>
                <AMOUNT>-2200.00</AMOUNT>
              </BILLALLOCATIONS.LIST>
            </ALLLEDGERENTRIES.LIST>
            <ALLLEDGERENTRIES.LIST>
              <REMOVEZEROENTRIES>No</REMOVEZEROENTRIES>
              <ISDEEMEDPOSITIVE>Yes</ISDEEMEDPOSITIVE>
              <LEDGERFROMITEM>No</LEDGERFROMITEM>
              <LEDGERNAME>Rental Income</LEDGERNAME>
              <AMOUNT>1000.00</AMOUNT>
              <CATEGORYALLOCATIONS.LIST>
                <CATEGORY>Primary Cost Category</CATEGORY>
                <COSTCENTREALLOCATIONS.LIST>
                  <NAME>Rental Income</NAME>
                  <AMOUNT>1000.00</AMOUNT>
                </COSTCENTREALLOCATIONS.LIST>
              </CATEGORYALLOCATIONS.LIST>
            </ALLLEDGERENTRIES.LIST>
            <ALLLEDGERENTRIES.LIST>
              <REMOVEZEROENTRIES>No</REMOVEZEROENTRIES>
              <ISDEEMEDPOSITIVE>No</ISDEEMEDPOSITIVE>
              <LEDGERFROMITEM>No</LEDGERFROMITEM>
              <LEDGERNAME>Parking N Toll</LEDGERNAME>
              <AMOUNT>1200.00</AMOUNT>
            </ALLLEDGERENTRIES.LIST>
          </VOUCHER>
        </TALLYMESSAGE>
      </REQUESTDATA>
    </IMPORTDATA>
  </BODY>
</ENVELOPE>


    And here is my php:
    $server = "http://".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'].":9000";
     $headers = array( "Content-type: text/xml" ,"Content-length: ".strlen($strXML) ,"Connection: close" );

    $ch = curl_init(); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$server);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $strXML);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    $server_output = curl_exec($ch);



    if(curl_errno($ch)){
        echo curl_error($ch);
        echo " $server  something went wrong..... try later ";
        if($_GET[counter]==$_GET[total])
        echo 'done###';
    }else{

        curl_close($ch);
    }
```

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: the problem is i am not able it send data to tally over the external network

Comment: Did you try connecting to the Tally ERP on port 9000?

Comment: did you soved it ?

Comment: Did you Solved ??